# $text search in mongoose only looking on one field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I run into a weird problem and I haven´t been able to figure it out. I have an schema in mongoose with about 20 keys and I would like to use the $text query in 5 of them, it looks like this:

```
var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstkey:{type: String, index: true},
    secondkey:{type:String,index: true},
    thirdkey:{type:String,index: true},
    fourthkey:{type:String,index: true},
    fifthkey:{type:String,index: true},
    sixth:String,
    seventh:String,
    .... });

mySchema.index=({'firstkey':'text','secondkey':'text','thirdkey':'text','fourthkey':'text','fifthkey':'text'})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Schema", mySchema);
```

Then in my route file I perform the following query:

```
if (req.query.search) {
    Schema.find({ $text: { $search: req.query.search } }, function (err, allRecords) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("records/index", { records: allRecords });
        }
    });
}
```

I get the value for `req.query.search` from a search form in the page, anyway if the word I enter into the form is a value that can be found in the firstkey I get the correct result no problem, but If I enter a value that I know exist on one of the other keys my query turns up empty.

Any idea of why $text is not looking into the other keys I tried to index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out, at some point when creating the schema a different index was created, one with only the first key selected was the culprit, so I erased all the indexes and created the index I wanted from the console and now I'm good to go!